# Is it possible to sort the list of pair <string ,node> on c++,, based upon one of the attribute(string) of node ? How?

Tags: list, data-structures, c++14, key-value, std-pair

//THis is how list of pair  has defined

`list<pair<string,car> >car_details;`

//node creation

```
struct car{
    string id;
    string date;
    string etime;
    string exit_time;
    double price;
};
```

`car carnode{id, date, s2, s1, amount};`
//id,date,s2,s1  -string , amount -double

insert is being performed like this,
`car_details.push_back(make_pair(id,carnode));`

//Actually want to sort based upon that entrytime(etime) attribute ( which is string in the format HH:MM:SS) like ( "08:35:20")

Comment: Yes? That's what [the `.sort` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort), called with a comparator, is for. A simple lambda comparing the `.first` attribute (for your original question) or `.second.etime` (for your edit) would do the trick.

Comment: I didn't get it to implement lambda ,can u please elaborate it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.